# How to write Xpath for dynamic value passing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

How to write Xpath for the following:

```
<input class="t2" style="background-color:#008000;" title="Jump to Detailed Analysis" type="button" value="Analyze" onclick="javascript:popAnalyze
(&quot;1622662&quot;,&quot; SP0001622662&quot;,&quot;CS3_pro2_axeda6&quot;,&quot;5336293761&quot;);">
```

[image: screenshot]

Highlighted values are there in some variable(st_name). Highlighted and Red colour rounded values will be changing dynamically.
I'm not able to get how to write Xpath for this.

```
import xlrd

path = r'C:\Users\tmou\PycharmProjects\Python\WebScraping\Book2.xlsx'
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
for c in range(sheet.ncols):
    for r in range(sheet.nrows):
        st = (sheet.cell_value(r, c))
        try:
            if st == float(st):
                st_string = int(st)
                #variable = 1622662
                #new_string = "javascript:popAnalyze(&quot;" + str(st_string) + "&quot;,&quot;SP0001622662&quot;,&quot;CS3_pro2_axeda6&quot;,&quot;5336293761&quot;);"
                #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='t2']/@onclick='" + st_string + "'").click()
                #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Analyze' and contains(@onclick='" + st_string + "']")
                #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='" + st_string + "']")
```

HTML:

```
<input class="t2" style="background-color:#008000;" title="Jump to Detailed Analysis" type="button" value="Analyze" onclick="javascript:popAnalyze(&quot;1622662&quot;,&quot;SP0001622662&quot;,&quot;CS3_pro2_axeda6&quot;,&quot;5336293761&quot;);">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this without the value of `onclick`, so don't bother even if it is dynamic, like shown below:

```
//input[@title='Jump to Detailed Analysis']
```

or

```
//input[@value='Analyze']
```

or

```
//input[@value='Analyze' and @title='Jump to Detailed Analysis']
```

**EDIT 1:**

You can use variable like shown below:

```
variable = "Analyze"
xpath = "//input[@value='" + variable + "']"
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
variable = 1622662
new_string = "javascript:popAnalyze(&quot;" + str(variable) + "&quot;,&quot;SP0001622662&quot;,&quot;CS3_pro2_axeda6&quot;,&quot;5336293761&quot;);"
```

**EDIT 3:**

```
variable = 1622662
xpath = "//input[@value='Analyze' and contains(@onclick,'" + str(variable) + "')]"

if driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

- In the above code `variable` will be your dynamic value.
- `xpath` variable will have a dynamic xpath based on the value of
  `variable`
- `if driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath):` will check if at least one
  element with the xpath exit
- if exists exits click on it

Comment: Thanthu, How to pass variable(st_name)?

Comment: You just have to append that variable to the string that is your xpath like how you would with any string, I've added a sample to the answer

Comment: Here Analyze isn't a Variable, 1622662 is my variable onclick="javascript:popAnalyze(&quot;1622662&quot;,&quot;SP0001622662&quot;,&quot;CS3_pro2_axeda6&quot;,&quot;5336293761&quot;);">

Comment: Yes, a variable can be anything right, you can give it the value 1622662 also, take a look at second edit. There since it is a number we have to cast it to string using str()

Comment: I don't want to find the elements after + str(variable) + Because those values also will change.

Comment: SP0001622662&quot;,&quot;CS3_pro2_axeda6&quot;,&quot;5336293761&quot                                                    This values also will be changing W.R.T variable

Comment: This is another HTML:  <input class="t2" style="background-color:#008000;" title="Jump to Detailed Analysis" type="button" value="Analyze" onclick="javascript:popAnalyze(&quot;CZ3548NKYT&quot;,&quot;SPCZ3548NKYT&quot;,&quot;domino&quot;,&quot;5332999684&quot;);">

Comment: Okay. So you want to check if onclick has CZ3548NKYT or some dynamic value and identify the element ? Is that correct ?

Comment: yes, i need to check whether the element is there or not and if it is there it has to click on the ANALYZE button. In the file(Excel) I'll be having N no. of elements.

Comment: Okay take a look at EDIT 3: in the answer, may be that is the solution you are looking for

Comment: It's working.....If i want to perform any action on the second window do i need pass that url in the Xpath?  if yes, URL also will be changing W.R.T the Variable. How to write Xpath for the second window? I tried the following way, But couldn't work...

Comment: xpath = "//input[@value='Analyze' and contains(@onclick,'" + st_string + "')]"
                c=0
                if driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath):
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click() #Here new window will open
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Create New Case'").click() # one more time new window will open
                    driver.close()
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("input[@id='create_button'").click()
                    c+=1
                print(c)

Comment: new window URL will be like : https://example.com/st/xxx_xxx_status_analysis.php?xyz_id=1622662&mn_id=SP0001622662&server_id=CS3_pro2_axeda6&case_id=5336293761     and HTML is :   <input class="t2" type="button" value="Create New Case" onclick="javascript:popCaseCreate(&quot;1622662&quot;);">

Comment: If a new window is opening you'll have to first switch to that window before you can find element in that window using driver.switch_to_window(), if the issue you asked for in this question is solved can you accept the answer and ask this as a new question. The answer and comment section us already crowded and this will also help others find the issue easily.

Answer (score 2):

If the value that you are looking for is the one under **onclick** attribute then the following Xpath expression should work:

```
string(//input[@class='t2']/@onclick)
```

**Edit 1**

Can you try for XPath version 3 or lower:

```
//input[(@class='t2' and matches(@onclick,'1622662'))]
```

And for XPath version 3.1:

```
//input[@class='t2']/[matches(@onclick, '1622662')]
```

Comment: How to pass variable(st_name)?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='t2']/@onclick='" + st_string + "'").click()

Comment: Raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //input[@class='t2']/@onclick='1622662' because of the following error:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.

Answer (score 0):

**Use one of the following XPath :**

```
//input[@value='Analyze' and contains(@onclick,'"+st_name+"')]
```

OR

```
//input[@title='Jump to Detailed Analysis' and contains(@onclick,'"+st_name+"')]
```

**`Final Code :`**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='Jump to Detailed Analysis' and contains(@onclick,'"+st_name+"')]")
```

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //input[@value='Analyze' and contains(@onclick='1622662'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//input[@value='Analyze' and contains(@onclick='1622662']' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: @Mounika : you have missed one paranthesis, check it one, I have closing ')' brace mentioned but you have not added it

Comment: It's working.. If possible can you please check the below question and let me know the answer.

Comment: @MounikaKrishna : Which question ? provide the link

Comment: @MounikaKrishna : I have gone through provided link, It is the same question.

Comment: @MounikaKrishna : If you have any specific concern, mentioned it properly so that I can help you ?

Comment: @MounikaKrishna : Is above provided answer worked for you ? I mean able to resolve your issue ? If yes the could you please accept the answer ?

Comment: It's working.....If i want to perform any action on the second window do i need pass that url in the Xpath? if yes, URL also will be changing W.R.T the Variable. How to write Xpath for the second window? I tried the following way, But couldn't work 
xpath = "//input[@value='Analyze' and contains(@onclick,'" + st_string + "')]"  if driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath): driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click() #Here new window will open driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Create New Case'").click() driver.find_element_by_xpath("input[@id='create_button'").click()

Comment: new window URL will be like : example.com/st/… and HTML is : <input class="t2" type="button" value="Create New Case" onclick="javascript:popCaseCreate(&quot;1622662&quot;);">

Comment: @MounikaKrishna : Could you please add another question for that? Then it will be easier for you as well as for me

Comment: .If i want to perform any action on the second window do i need pass that url in the Xpath? if yes, URL also will be changing W.R.T the Variable. How to write Xpath for the second window?